# Trying to create multi-dimensional arrays programmatically

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im testing my ability to create multi dimensional arrays with for loops with:

```
        for (var a = 0; a < 3; a++){
            var pax[a] = new Array();
            pax[a].push(1,2,3);
        }

        console.log(pax[2][1],pax[0][0]);
```

But its giving me a syntax error unexpected token at the `[` of `var pax[a]`

I think it actually might be a scope error vs a syntax error, but I cant be sure.

Comment: `var pax[a]` is invalid syntax. Isn't the console telling you that?

Comment: `pax` is a variable, `pax[a]` is an expression that refers to an element from the array or object that's the value of the `pax` variable.

Comment: as a side note, the preferred JavaScript syntax for arrays is `var pax = [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syntax issue as @Barmar pointed out.

try...

```
var pax = new Array();
 for (var a = 0; a < 3; a++){
    pax[a] = new Array();
    pax[a].push(1,2,3);
}

console.log(pax[2][1],pax[0][0]);
```

Comment: The updated code is correct, but it's not a scope issue. JS has function scope, not block scope. It's a syntax issue.